# JOIN for Membership table

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, entity-framework

Why Microsoft uses stupid examples with GroupBy clause only for one table?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896341.aspx

And why error is causing when i tried to Select some field that is not in GroupBy?
Error says that fields that is not in GroupBy clause doesn't exist in current context.

```
using (Entities db = new Entities())
{
    var query = "SELECT RLS.RoleId, UIR.UserId, UIR.RoleId, USR.UserName FROM Entities.aspnet_Roles AS RLS " +
                 "INNER JOIN Entities.vw_aspnet_UsersInRoles AS UIR " +
                 "ON RLS.RoleId = UIR.RoleId " + 
                 "INNER JOIN Entities.aspnet_Users AS USR " + 
                 "ON UIR.UserId = USR.UserId " + 
                 //"GROUP BY RLS.RoleId"  // is uncomment - it says UserId doesn't exist in context
                 ;
    var x = new ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord>(query, db);
    var y = x.ToTraceString().Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\t", " ").Replace("\r", " ");
}
```

The same for LINQ:

```
var x = from RLS in db.aspnet_Roles
                        join URS in db.vw_aspnet_UsersInRoles
                        on RLS.RoleId equals URS.RoleId
                        join USR in db.aspnet_Users
                        on URS.UserId equals USR.UserId
                        group RLS by RLS.RoleId into GRP
                        select new
                        {
                            GRP.Key
                        };
```

**The question is: how to select all fields and GroupBy selection by only one field?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain more how you expect to select all the fields and also group the records? Are you looking for unique sets of fields, in which case you are looking for DISTINCT, or are you looking to have the records delivered with all the entries with the same RoleId together, in which case you are looking for ORDERBY.

Comment: it still amazes me when people try and map the membership tables and query against it via the EF model - use the provider API!

Comment: RPM1984: if you are so smart, in this case you could answer how to add OrderBy, Distinct and select all users in 3 roles + those who are out of any role with Provider API? I have few roles and few users in them. One user can appear in multiple roles. To prevent users duplication i want to group selection result by RoleId.

Comment: Lazarus: probably you are right, in my case it is better to use DISTINCT. Thanks.

Comment: Lazarus: though no, actually DISTINCT doesn't help because this is a JOINed result so record in any case will be different ... so this is a case for GROUP BY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All fields that are not in the `GROUP BY` clause have to be aggregate expressions such as `AVG(...)` or `SUM(...)` or `MAX(...)` etc.

So this is wrong:

```
SELECT RLS.RoleId, UIR.UserId, UIR.RoleId, USR.UserName
(...)
GROUP BY RLS.RoleId
```

because the last three expressions in the `SELECT` should either be aggregated somehow or added to the `GROUP BY` clause.

This is logical because by specifying `GROUP BY RLS.RoleId` you say that RLS.RoleId should be unique in the end result, so only one row per value. But for each RLS.RoleID there could be multiple values for UIR.UserId, UIR.RoleId or USR.UserName. So you need to tell the DBMS what to do to make them into one row: average, maximum, minimum... OR you add fields to the GROUP BY clause, so that not RLS.RoleID but the *combination* of column values should be unique. See also this [example](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-GROUP-BY.asp).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any aggregate functions (COUNT, SUM, AVG, etc) being used in the query you posted.  Thus, there's no need to include a GROUP BY expression, and there's really no reason to do so.  Could you please explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have few roles and few users in them. One user can appear in multiple roles. To prevent users duplication i want to group selection result by RoleId.

Comment: OK but for which user role do you want the result?

Comment: For example if this is a "Manager" then it should contain users for three roles - Manager, Customer, User and also "anonymous", i.e. those who are out of these roles (role Administrator also should be excluded). So the condition should be like this - WHERE RoleName IN (Manager, Customer, User) OR RoleName = NULL

Answer (score 0):

I think i didn't understand **littlegreen**.
His advice really helped ... though i was upset by SQL Server comparing to MySQL (there is enough to set one grouping field).

Works!

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   RLS.RoleId, 
   COUNT(RLS.RoleId) AS RID_CNT, 
   MAX(CAST(UIR.UserId AS VARCHAR(36))) AS EXPR1, 
   MAX(CAST(USR.UserName AS VARCHAR(36))) AS EXPR2
FROM aspnet_Roles AS RLS 
INNER JOIN vw_aspnet_UsersInRoles AS UIR ON RLS.RoleId = UIR.RoleId 
INNER JOIN aspnet_Users AS USR ON UIR.UserId = USR.UserId
GROUP BY RLS.RoleId
```

Comment: The `DISTINCT` isn't necessary in this case, since you're already grouping by RoleID.

Comment: I'm happy this works for you, but is this really the query you want? Now it will display per role the number of users, and the alphanumerically highest UserID and UserName for the role, which are not necessarily the same. Eg. when you have in RoleID 'managers' a user 81 called Zacharias and user 9 called Andrew, it will display a row of: **Managers, 2, 9, Zacharias** which seems to me to be of no real use. Is that really what you want to show?

Comment: In this case i will just add UserId to GROUP BY clause - GROUP BY RLS.RoleId, USR.UserId